# Java 11 Standard Environment incompatible with ApiProxy?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-11

I've got an app running in App Engine's Java 11 standard environment, where I want to make sure that Tasks are called on a particular version of the app (the one creating them). I can add the `AppEngineRouting` field to the task creation request to achieve this, but there's a catch: *normally*, the version ID is accessible using `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getVersionId()`, or at least it used to be under the venerable Java 8 standard environment. Under Java 11, `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()` is consistently `null` for me.

Am I missing something, or has `ApiProxy` been secretly "deprecated" for Java 11 standard? And if so, what is the currently accepted method of getting info like app, version and service IDs, or milliseconds remaining before request deadline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of looking around, I realized that under the Java 11 Standard Environment system, these are available as App Engine-set envvars [1]. If you need to get things that previously used to be available in `ApiProxy`, you best bet is to read the corresponding variable via `System.getenv(String name)`.

Further, you can set custom envvars in the `app.yaml` file, without having to pass them to your program via `-Dname=value`.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#environment_variables